# Difference between "sorts" vs. "kinds" vs. "types"

Tags: comparison, idiomatic-language

I am Brazilian and I often read the terms "sorts," "kinds" and "types."

To me, they each have the same meaning. Is there a difference for the native English speakers?

**Context:**

> Does NAG develop the same **sorts** of products as our local Boston area
>   company MathWorks (e.g., MATLAB)? And why/how is XML important to math
>   software products?

Source: https://tug.org/interviews/carlisle.html

Comment: Before posing a question, you should always use the search field above right ("Search Q&A") to see whether your question has already been asked and answered.